# How to replace elements in sql

Tags: sql, replace

I got an array like that :

```
name      Description

R          mono        
R          mono

Q          trio
Q          trio
Q          duo
```

My aim is to say " when Q="duo" then Q= "R" but I must do that in SQL.

Then I got it :

```
name      Description

R          mono        
R          mono
R           duo

Q          trio
Q          trio
```

Thanks for reading me

Comment: A table is not an array so I'm confused from the get-go.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly but if what you are looking is to replace the column name for the the row where descriptions is equal to mono, this should be work:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET name = 'R' where Description = 'duo';
```

This will update rows with description as duo and will change the name to `R`.